# What is the ideal temp for intel j4205 procesor?

Tags: windows-10, cpu, temperature

Hi i have an intel j4205 procesor.

When it's idle the temps are between 35 and 45 degree.

On load it's between 48 and 64 degree and sometimes it goes up to 68 degree then goes down when viewing a complex website on chrome.

On max usage it can sometimes hit 73 degree and with the integrated gpu at max usage it can hit 81 degree.

So are those temps normal ?? because i have searched for normal cpu temps on the internet and every answer was about desktop and laptops that must not reach 70 degree but never find an answer to my case as i have a mini pc.

Thank's.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The T junction (Junction Temperature is the maximum temperature allowed at the processor die) for the j4205 is 105°C

See : https://ark.intel.com/content/www/us/en/ark/products/95591/intel-pentium-processor-j4205-2m-cache-up-to-2-6-ghz.html

Your temperatures are absolutely fine.

Comment: Ok, but what if it runs between 70 and 80 degree for a long time ?? will that affect the cpu in terms of it's life ??

Comment: Possibly.  There is a similar question here [Will higher temperatures damage a computer over time even when not reaching max?](https://superuser.com/questions/623127/will-higher-temperatures-damage-a-computer-over-time-even-when-not-reaching-max) which was closed as "too broad" but may allay your concerns somewhat.  FWIW I've been running my X201 laptop pretty much 24*7 since 2010 and it idles at almost 70°C so in my case it doesn't seem to matter.

Comment: Ok, thank's for the answers.